# Sync an entire collection of models in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am attempting to sync an entire collection of models to the server in backbone.js. I want to POST a JSON package to the server containing all of the collection's model's attributes. This should be pretty simple but Im not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
      var RegisterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    initialize: function () {_(this).bindAll('syncCollection');},

    model: RegisterModel, 

    url: 'api/process.php',
    updateModel: function(registerModel) {
        var inputName = '#'+registerModel.get('inputName');
        var userInput = $(inputName).val();
        registerModel.set({value: userInput});
    },
    syncCollection: function(registerModel) {
        this.sync();
    }

});
var RegisterCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#register",
    events: {
        "click #submit" : "validate"
    },

    validate: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#register").valid();
        if ($("#register").valid() === true) {
            this.updateModels();
            this.collection.syncCollection();
        }
    },
    updateModels: function (){
        this.collection.forEach(this.collection.updateModel, this);;    
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },  
    addOne: function(registerModel){
        var registerView = new RegisterView({model: registerModel});
        this.$el.append(registerView.render().el);  
    },
    addAll: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        this.$el.append('<button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" id="submit" style="display: block;">Submit</button>');
    },
    render: function(){
        this.addAll();
        return this;
    }
});
var registerCollection = new RegisterCollection();
registerCollection.fetch();

var registerCollectionView = new RegisterCollectionView({collection: registerCollection});
registerCollectionView.render();
```

When I try to call syncCollection(), it returns the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'` I'm new to Backbone, so odds are that I am making a fairly elementary mistake somewhere...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, a fresh pot of coffee and a day later, I got it. We were calling sync() improperly. Here is what we should have been doing:

```
syncCollection: function() {
        Backbone.sync('create', this);
    }
```

Thanks to machineghost for helping me explore this problem - I was totally focused on the wrong thing.

Comment: Ah, nice find.  Does using sync that way instead make a single AJAX request (vs. my solution which would make one request per model)?

Comment: If I recall, it did make a single request but Im not 100% sure. I started using Angular like a sane person and never looked back.

Comment: Angular !== 'sane'. Backbone = ♥

Comment: Fight fight fight fight! Nerd wars. Regardless of which is "better" they are both good for certain things, and sometimes you don't have a choice which to use. If your codebase is one you write it, not convert it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting that error is that `Backbone.Collection` does not have a save method (its models do).  What I think you're looking for is:

```
syncCollection: function() {
    _(this.models).each(function(model) {
        model.save();
    });
}
```

Or better yet, using `Collection`'s `each`:

```
syncCollection: function() {
    this.each(function(model) {
        model.save();
    });
}
```

Or better still, using `Collection`'s `invoke`:

```
syncCollection: function() {
    this.invoke('save');
}
```

However, I'm not sure you even need any of that, as `Backbone.Collection` already has a method that does (I think) what you want: `sync`.

From the Backbone docs:

> > collection.sync(method, collection, [options])
> >
> > Uses Backbone.sync to persist the state of a collection to the server. Can be overridden for custom behavior.

Comment: So, I tried sync but I am getting the same error. `syncCollection: function() {
  this.sync('create', this);
 }` - Am I still screwing something up?

Comment: If you are getting the exact same "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'" error, then yes you are doing something very wrong, because your code should no longer even have a 'save' call ;-)  But I doubt you're getting the *exact* same error, so could you please clarify exactly what error you got?

Comment: Also I can't help but wonder: how exactly are you invoking syncCollection ... it's not as a callback by any chance is it?  When callbacks get invoked they often change the "this" of the callback, if it hasn't been previously bound.  If you think this might be your problem, try calling `_(this).bindAll('syncCollection')` in your collection's `initialize` function.

Comment: Yes, I am using a call back so I tried your initialize binding which broke the script. I updated the original problem above so that you can see the full picture.

Comment: `initialize:_(this).bindAll('syncCollection')` so what you just said there was "make my initialize function the result of a bindAll call", which is obviously not what you want :-)  Try wrapping it in a function instead: `initialize: function() {_(this).bindAll('syncCollection');},`.

Comment: We must be on the same wavelength - I just realized that! Sadly, the error is still the same: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sync' `...

Comment: Could you please post the code where you instantiate `RegisterCollection` (ie. the code that does `new RegisterCollection()`)?

Comment: Hmmmm ... I think you need to do some debugging.  Can you add the line `console.log(this.collection)` just before the `this.collection.syncCollection();`?  Clearly `this.collection` isn't what we think it is, but I'm curious what it actually is.

Comment: P.S. For that to work you'll need a browser console, like the one from Firefox's Firebug extension (or Chrome's built-in dev tools).

Comment: Here is what it spit out: `d {length: 5, models: Array[5], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, syncCollection: function…` Looks like it is targeting the correct collection, since there are 5 models.

Comment: I think that you are reinventing the wheel here.